# How do I view the source of a Cordova app running in a web browser?

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app using Apache Cordova. (That's already my first problem.)

I would like to debug the HTML output that is produced at runtime, but I can't convince any of the three browsers available to me to show the source of the output pages.

- The internal browser in Eclipse doesn't appear to have a "View Source" option at all.
- Firefox can load the page, but it doesn't seem to be granting the app access to the web, so the remote data doesn't load.
- - (edit) The console error claims that the problem is related to CORS, but every search I've done of this issue claims that the CORS error is spurious, and "all I have to do" is add the remote data source to a list of security exceptions. Except that there is no apparent way to do this in Firefox.
- Chrome displays a blank screen. When inspected, even less of the app seems to be executed.

There is not enough `console.log`ging in the world to make my diagnostic efforts worthwhile when executing as an Android app.

So, how the heck do I debug my code?

Comment: You don't run the app in the browser. You run the app on a device or emulator/simulator and can then use a number of tools to debug and inspect. Google `remote debug phonegap app`

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing Android PhoneGap debugging and have an Android 4.4 device and Chrome 30+, you can use the new WebView Debugging tools added in Android 4.4. If you are using Cordova 3.3 or higher, this is already supported, and only requires the Debuggable flag in your AndroidManifest.xml. For Cordova 3.2, you will need to enable WebView debugging using some code, or by use of a plugin.

For additional info and links with detailed instructions check this:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap